# Get the specific child of IShellItem assuming IShellItem is a directory?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Using `IKnownFolderManager` and `IKnownFolder` I managed to get the path to C:\Program Files and its corresponding `IShellItem`. After that I managed to create a directory in that location using `IFileOperation`. Now, I want to create a file in the new directory. Since `IFileOperation` needs `IShellItem`, how do I get the corresponding `IShellItem` of the new directory?

PS: I'm new to COM and Win32 API.

Comment: From Microsoft official samples https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileoperations/FileOperationSample.cpp#L106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`IFileOperation::NewItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-newitem), you can use an [`IFileOperationProgressSink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperationprogresssink) object, its [`PostNewItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperationprogresssink-postnewitem) event will give you the `IShellItem` of the new item you create. You can either pass the sink object to `NewItem()` directly, or pass it to  [`IFileOperation::Advise()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-advise) before calling `IFileOperation::PerformOperations()`.

Alternatively, you can use [`SHCreateItemFromRelativeName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateitemfromrelativename) instead, after `PerformOperations()` is successful.